# Confirmation was required to visit untrusted URL

Tags: eclipse, gwt

Hi Im using eclipse-jee-galileo-win32 for development. I tried to install GWT using eclipse plugin for following link gwt - http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/3.5. But it will displayed following error. How can i solve this problem.

```
 [WARN] Confirmation was required to visit untrusted URL: 'http://gwt.google.com/missing-plugin
    [WARN] reason: http://gwt.google.com/missing-plugin is not in the whitelist
    whitelist: 
    blacklist: 

    To fix: add regex matching URL to -whitelist command line argument
       Example: -whitelist=" ^http[:][/][/]gwt[.]google[.]com"
    Example: -whitelist=" ^http[:][/][/]gwt[.]google[.]com"

    To reject automatically: add regex matching URL to -blacklist command line argument
       Example: -blacklist=" ^http[:][/][/]gwt[.]google[.]com"
    Example: -blacklist=" ^http[:][/][/]gwt[.]google[.]com"

    Unknown module requested 'missingplugin'; all active GWT modules must be specified in the command line arguments
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused due to your browser not having the necessary plugin to talk to GWT/Eclipse. Visit that page (http://gwt.google.com/missing-plugin) in your browser, install the plugin, restart the browser, retry the (local?) GWT page.